# Scaling Div Programmatically in CSS3 and Webkit

Tags: jquery, webkit

I'm trying to scale a square from 0 to 1.5, however it seems like it starts off the scale of 1.0. How can I make it start from 0?

If you check out my fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/eaPpT/

p.s please use a webkit compliant browser for this: chrome or safari.

*Note: I do not want to change the actual style or CSS for this, I want to do this completely programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery 1.8 adds the prefixes for you, but you should use `-webkit-transform`, rather than the JS version with the `.css()` method.

Also, to ensure that it works as expected, I've left a little amount of time before changing things:

http://jsfiddle.net/eaPpT/3/

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the timeout?

Comment: I'm not sure, the issue is that the JS doesn't wait for the scale 0 to be set before setting the 1.5 bit, they both happen at the same moment. The time out can be set to 0 even, and it still works.

Comment: I think there's a way to bind to webkitTransitionEnd, but I'll give you the benefit of the doubt. :>

Comment: The transition hasn't started yet at the point you want, that's the problem. The timeout is just a way of guaranteeing it happens afterwards. This is something that's bothered me for ages to be honest.